# How to plot the data obtained from .meas in LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice

I have used .meas in LTSPICE to find voltage at a particular time. I was able to see the values, but when I tried to plot them by right clicking, the graph was empty.
[image: The option I used]
[image: the empty plot]

Comment: Have you tried to click on the "Pick Visible Traces" from the toolbar? If there's more than one, LTspice will not try to guess which one you need.

Comment: oh I selected before plotting. Lemme try this @aconcernedcitizen

Comment: Where is this 'pick visible traces'? did you mean pick 'visible traces' ? visible traces does not contain  the values I want to plot. @aconcernedcitizen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got until the *Plot .step'ed .meas data*, so now a new window should appear. If more than one quantity is measured, LTspice can't read minds about which one to plot first, so nothing is shown; it will be a blank window. With *that* window active, click on the *Pick Visible Traces* button in the toolbar, the 11th icon from the left, the one between *Zoom full extents* and *Autorange*, this one:

[image: this]